# is __attribute__((section(".something"))) on a static member of a template class allowed?

Tags: c++, gcc, static, attributes

in the following example clang puts the respective variables in '.aaa' and '.ggg' correctly. GCC works on '.ggg' but not on '.aaa' (the static member variable of the class template).

```
template<int I>
struct s{
    __attribute__((section(".aaa"))) static  int a[100];
};

__attribute__((section(".ggg"))) int  b[100]; 

template<int I>
__attribute__((section(".aaa"))) int s<I>::a[100];
```

Is this a GCC bug or voluntary support on the part of clang?

Is there a good work around (besides making s::a a global rather than a static member)?

note: I left out the compiler version as all version of GCC on godbolt do essentially the same thing https://godbolt.org/g/E5s0mi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the official documentation of gcc says

> Use the section attribute with global variables and not local variables, as shown in the example.

local linkage = wrong?
static member variables are local if the class itself is local. 
and i would say its local through the template declaration.

[source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#AVR%20Variable%20Attributes)

Comment: I do not see how the template declaration would relate to the class being local. A class is local, if it is defined inside functions. According to [cppreference.com (section "static data members")](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static), the static data member has *external linkage* as long as the class is declared at namespace scope, as in the OPs example on godbolt.