# Annotating linker section of a variable in a type - static memory management problem for embedded c++

Tags: c++, arm, g++

## A bit of introduction to the architecture

First a bit about target architecture, if anyone finds it useful - Target it STM32H7 series microcontroller - it's ARM Cortex-M7 with a lot of different memory regions located on different busses around the chip, in particular:

- ITCM memory - 64Kb RAM as fast as the core, used for storing instructions, not accesible by normal DMA
- DTCM memory - 128Kb RAM as fast as the core, used for storing data, not accessible by normal DMA
- AXI SRAM - 512Kb RAM on 64-bit bus (AXI) that runs at half CPU clock (but because it's 64-bit it is as fast as core for sequential reads)
- SRAM 1/2/3 - RAM memories located on AHB bus, that connects through AXI bus - slower to access by CPU, but on the same AHB bus matrix are DMA controllers and most of the peripherals used by the application
- SRAM4 and Backup RAM - other memories located in another part of chip on different bus matrix, not important here

A special kind of DMA - MDMA - can transfer data between I/DTCM memories and other RAM's in the system.

## Example real-world problem

As an example of a problem suppose that I want to create a c++ class that will deal with sending data over serial port. The requirements are:

- Data to UART is sent using DMA - the application can't spend cycles on using interrupts here.
- Queue for data to be send out has to be located in DTCM memory, so if I write `serial_write(some_data_to_send)` it is going to be copied to the queue without wait states (if `some_data_to_send` is located in DTCM as well)
- Buffer for DMA should be located in one of SRAM 1/2/3 (so DMA transactions don't use AXI bus), cannot be located in I/DTCM memories
- Data from queue to DMA buffer should be copied using MDMA

That means that the class needs at least:

- Buffer that is guaranteed to be in DTCM ram
- Buffer that is guaranteed to be not in DTCM ram

That means that it cannot be part of the same object, i.e. I can't write something like:

```cpp
class serial_handler
{
  __attribute__((section(".dtcm"))) std::array<std::uint8_t, 128> m_send_queue;
  __attribute__((section(".sram1"))) std::array<std::uint8_t, 128> m_dma_buffer;
};
```

*Note: It it also not possible to make these variables static - this class might exist in multiple instances handling multiple serial ports*

Thus I need to pass the buffer from the outside, i.e.

```cpp
class serial_handler
{
public:
  using buffer_type = std::array<std::uint8_t, 128>;
private:
  buffer_type &m_send_queue;
  buffer_type &m_dma_buffer;
public:
  /**
   * @param send_queue buffer located in DTCM ram
   * @param dma_buffer buffer located in SRAM 1,2 or 3
   */
  serial_handler(buffer_type &send_queue, buffer_type &dma_buffer);
};

// ...
static __attribute__((section(".dtcm"))) serial_handler::buffer_type s_serial_send_queue;
static __attribute__((section(".sram1"))) serial_handler::buffer_type s_serial_dma_buffer;
static serial_handler serial{s_serial_send_queue, s_serial_dma_buffer};
```

But now information about location of buffers is encoded in a comment. The `serial_handler` could (and probably should) assert that passed buffers are in correct address spaces, but that is a runtime check and I would like a compile time error.

Another solution would be to create a memory pool for each section and allocate memory from required region, but again - that is a runtime solution and also that doesn't permit static memory usage analysis.

## Abstract problem description

Suppose that the linker has two additional sections - `.dtcm` and `.sram1`. I want to create a class with a constructor that takes two statically allocated buffers (pointers, references, other temporary objects holding reference that will be optimized away) - one from each section:

```
struct example
{
  example(IN_DTCM buffer_type_ref buffer_1, IN_SRAM1 buffer_type_ref buffer_2);
};
```

I want it in such a way that it will emit a compile time error if provided variable is *not* in required section. Alternatively the constructor can allocate memory from other objects, but it has be done in such a way that is statically analyzable at link time.

This object will only ever be constructed in a static context (i.e. either a global or static variable in class/function).

*EDIT*: Clarifying after some comments - the ideal solution would be to create types `dtcm_buffer_type` and `sram1_buffer_type` that would always be placed in apropriate sections (i.e. they could only exist in a static context, never on stack which could be in any memory region). I don't believe that such solution is possible, that's why in the example above I used `IN_DTCM` placeholder.

## Final comments

This problem has been taunting me for well over a year now, and I have't found anything that might be even close to meeting the requirements above. I was able to create static allocator using templates (i.e. allocator that lives in a specified memory section but is able to report at link time it's usage), but that is simply not feasible to use in a project over 100,000 lines long.

My current solution is passing buffers from outside and using runtime asserts on memory addresses of provided buffers - but that far from ideal, especially if one forgets to put the assert - that often leads to very hard to diagnose bugs (for example performance problem in completely unrelated part of code due to bus matrix saturation - been there, done that).

The solution can be gcc/g++ specific, but it would be nice if it worked in clang as well.

Comment: Why not just have different *types* for objects that serve different purposes?

Comment: Because that doesn't solve the problem of required memory placement.

Comment: You need to create a *type* that enforces memory placement.

Comment: And how do I go about that? That's the point of this question - it's not like I can put `section` attribute on type - that wouldn't make sense (consider instantiating the type on the stack - this should not be possible then)

Comment: I edited the question to clarify that this would be preferred solution - if possible to execute.

Comment: Write an allocator that allocates from each kind of memory, then you can have `using send_queue = std::vector<uint8_t, dtcm_allocator>` and `using dma_buffer = std::vector<uint8_t, sram_allocator>`. (If you cannot use a vector, make your own std::array-like class, fixed size but allocatable). The simplest allocator can just use a fixed-size static array as a memory pool, and only allocate fixed-size chunks.

Comment: I mentioned this as a possibility, but it is not a solution - I want static memory allocation, such that I can trace memory usage and object's locations at link time. Using an allocator (probably memory pool with pointer bumping) changes the asserts from pointer address to allocation size/available space and makes static analysis harder.

Comment: It is also possible to allocate statically. Think two families of very simple allocators, each having its own type. Each object gets its own allocator of a unique type, getting memory from a static address. You will need to parameterize the type by something unique, e.g. source location (need a macro) or port number.

Comment: I don't quite grasp your concept, could please you write an answer with example of it?

Comment: I will try to write an answer later

Comment: I tried to make an answer but stumbled into a g++ bug. If you have a class template and a static member with a section attribute, this attribute gets ignored.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42517935/3449622) it's not a bug. But it doesn't matter, please put your idea into an answer - use conrete types and not a template if necessary - making int useful in more general sense can come later if the idea is good.

Comment: The answer is incorrect. Template members are every bit as global as non-template members.

Comment: And I cannot do this with clang because it does not support general non-type template parameters yet

Answer (score 0):

Here is a semi-working (with gcc and clang using c++17) implementation. The idea is to force each buffer to have its own type. In this implementation an additional level of indirection is required. Unfortunately we have to rely on macros.

```
using buffer_type = std::array<std::uint8_t, 128>;
struct buffer {
    virtual buffer_type& send_queue() = 0;
    virtual buffer_type& dma_buffer() = 0;
};

#define DECLARE_BUFFER_TYPE(name) \
struct buffer_impl_ ## name : buffer { \
    static inline __attribute__((section(".dtcm")))  buffer_type s_serial_send_queue; \
    static inline __attribute__((section(".sram1"))) buffer_type s_serial_dma_buffer; \
    buffer_type& send_queue() override { return s_serial_send_queue; } \
    buffer_type& dma_buffer() override { return s_serial_dma_buffer; } \
}; \

#define DECLARE_BUFFER(name) DECLARE_BUFFER_TYPE(name); buffer_impl_ ## name name;
```

Declare a buffer as follows:

```
DECLARE_BUFFER(mybuf1);
```

Each buffer declared this way has its own class and so its own set of static variables. The library uses `buffer&` as the parameter type.

```
serial_handler(buffer& b);
```

It is very hard to pass a wrong type accidentally, though of course it is easy to do so intentionally.